# Unable to load CSS files when deploying to Kubernetes with Ngnix Ingress Controller

Tags: css, kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am new to kubernetes. Please don't mind in answering this silly question.
I am deploying 2 micro-services each with different functionality to AKS cluster.
I was able see css files loading for microservice-1 but not for microservice-2.
When I deployed each microservice with Loadbalancer I was able to see the web applications without any errors. But when I was deploying with Ngnix Ingress controller I see errors.
Even if I use the same Ingress file for both microservices I got the errors for Ingress for microservices-2.
AKS Cluster I am deploying is of size 2 CPU's, 8 GB RAM and 16 GB internal memory. Image size is of around 500 MB.

I have used the following for ingress-ngnix

```
# Add the ingress-nginx repository
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

# Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --namespace dev --set controller.replicaCount=1 --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

**MICROSERVICE-1**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: dev
  labels: 
    name: dev
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice-1
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: microservice-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-1
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: microservice-1
        image: microservice-1:f1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservice-1-service
  namespace: dev
spec: 
  selector:
    app: microservice-1
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 5000
  type: ClusterIP
```

**MICROSERVICE-2**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: dev
  labels: 
    name: dev
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: microservice-2
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: microservice-2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-2
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: microservice-2
        image: microservice-2:f1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: microservice-2-service
  namespace: dev
spec: 
  selector:
    app: microservice-2
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 5001
  type: ClusterIP
```

**INGRESS FOR MICROSERVICE-1**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: microservice-1-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: microservice-1-service
            servicePort: 5000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: microservice-1-ingress-static
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /static
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /static
          backend:
            serviceName: microservice-1-service
            servicePort: 5000
```

**INGRESS FOR MICROSERVICE-2**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: microservice-2-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /app1
          backend:
            serviceName: microservice-2-service
            servicePort: 5001
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: microservice-1-ingress-static
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /static
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /static
          backend:
            serviceName: microservice-2-service
            servicePort: 5001
```

Comment: Are you having errors for both apps using nginx ingress? Please run `kubectl describe ingress %your_ingress_name%`, it will show all information and backends

Comment: Only for the second microservice

Comment: I think you have an incorrect ingress name for the microservice-2. you have `metadata:
  name: microservice-1-ingress-static` while it should be 2. If you've already corrected it, please run 'kubectl describe ingress icroservice-2-ingress` and `kubectl describe ingress microservice-2-ingress-static`. It will show backends and services which are mapped